# switch case matching with array index value

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing, range

I have this function in which I want to assign the values of img array that has 1 to 4 numbers, and I want to put red,yellow,green,blue into array matrixColored, but when I use switch case it gives erros in 4th line, help me thanks.

```
def colorPrint():
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        match img[i][j]:
            case 1:
                matrixColored[i][j] = 'red'
            case 2:
                matrixColored[i][j] = 'green'
            case 3:
                matrixColored[i][j] = 'blue'
            case 4:
                matrixColored[i][j] = 'yellow'
            case _:
                return "something went wrong"
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using ?  I believe 'match' only came out at version 3.10. BTW this would be much more efficient using a dictionary instead.

Comment: I'm using the last version, but sorry what is (BTW)?

Comment: BTW = By The Way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say what the problem is without the error message but, match is not the only way to do this.

Here's an example using a dictionary:

```
colorDict = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue', 4:'yellow'}

img = 3
color = colorDict.get(img)
if img in colorDict:
    matrixColored = colorDict[img]
    print(matrixColored)
else:
    print('something went wrong')
```

In your code example, this would transpose to :

```
def colorPrint():
    colorDict = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue', 4:'yellow'}
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            if img[i][j] in colorDict:
                matrixColored[i][j] = colorDict[img[i][j]]
            else:
                print('something went wrong')
```